# Memory leak using repository in iteration (In dev env)

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, repository, entity, shopware6

Hello I'm running into memory leakage when trying to create a lot of product reviews using the following code:

```
echo "Start: " . memory_get_usage();
foreach ($reviews['items'] as $review) {
    $newReview = $this->handleReviewData($review, $languages, $salesChannels, $context);

    if ($newReview) {
        $reviewsToImport[] = $newReview;
    }
    echo "End: " . memory_get_usage();
}

$this->productReviewRepository->create($reviewsToImport, $context);
```

I'm running multiple queries on `$this->productReviewRepository` within `$this->handleReviewData`. So I'm guessing that somehow creates the leak, but I can't find a `->flush()` or `->clear($entity)` (because it isn't Symfony). Any idea's?

It adds `+-1000000 bytes` (`1mb`) of memory for each iteration.

HandleReviewData function:

```
public function handleReviewData($review, $languages, $salesChannels, $context): ?array
{
    $reviewLocaleCode = $review['questionnaire']['locale'];
    $productSku = $review['product']['sku'];
    $salesChannels = $salesChannels->filter(static function ($salesChannel) use ($review) {
        /* @var $salesChannel TrustApiEntity */
        return $salesChannel->getChannelId() === $review['channelRef'];
    });

    $salesChannelId = $salesChannels->first()?->getSalesChannel()->getId();

    if (!$salesChannelId) {
        return null;
    }

    $languageId = array_search(str_replace('_', '-', $reviewLocaleCode), $languages, true);

    if (!$languageId) {
        return null;
    }

    $products = $this->productRepository
        ->search((new Criteria())
            ->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productNumber',
                $productSku))
            , $context);

    $productId = $products->first()?->getId();

    if (!$productId) {
        return null;
    }

    $existingReview = $this->productReviewRepository
        ->searchIds((new Criteria())
            ->addFilter(
                new EqualsFilter('title', $review['title']),
                new EqualsFilter('content', $review['comment'])
            )
            , $context)->getIds();

    if (count($existingReview) > 0) {
        return null;
    }


    return [
        'productId' => $productId,
        'salesChannelId' => $salesChannelId,
        'languageId' => $languageId,
        'externalUser' => $review['customer']['firstName'] ?? 'Anonymous',
        'externalEmail' => $review['customer']['email'] ?? 'anonymous',
        'title' => $review['title'],
        'content' => $review['comment'],
        'points' => round($review['rating'], 0),
        'status' => true,
        'createdAt' => new \DateTime('@' . strtotime($review['createdAt']))
    ];
}
```

Comment: And yes, I am running it inside of the `dev` environment. Running it in `prod` would probably fix it, but I would also like to test it in `dev`.

Comment: I can confirm running it in the `prod` environment fixes it.

Comment: Would you like to add "in dev env" to title? :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think this is intended behaviour. I encountered similiar issues when doing migrations from other systems to Shopware 6, where also a lot of data is read and written.

The issue with this is no issue in Shopware itself but the underlying Symfony framework because in `dev` environment the Symfony profiler is logging a lot of data for the current request which leads to huge amounts of memory used. I've seen it grow to several GB of data.